# How to test a constructor call in JMockit for the following piece of code

Tags: jmockit

```
public class HuronClassloader extends URLClassLoader {

  public HuronClassloader(Logger logger) {

    super(new URL[0]);
    this.logger = logger;
  }

  public void doLogic() throws ClasspathFormattingException {

      // logic go heer
  }
```

// How to test the doLogic method using JMockit?

Comment: Can't you simply do `new HuronClassloader(null).doLogic()` and verify whatever's important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as follows; @Injectable will automatically inject the mock Logger object to the constructor when initializing your tested class.

```
import mockit.Injectable;
import mockit.Tested;
...


@Tested
HuronClassloader loader;
@Injectable
Logger logger;


@Test
public void testSomeMethod() {
    //Optionally you can set expectation on your mock
    new Expectations() {{
        logger.someMethod(); result = ...;
    }};
    loader.doLogic();
}
```